# Cramér–Rao bound to multiple parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, optimization, likelihood, fisher-information, hessian

I was reading Cramér–Rao bound to multiple parameters from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case),  but I could not follow this line in the article:

> Let $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X)$ be an estimator of any    vector function of parameters...

I could not understand what $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X)$ and $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol{\psi}}({\boldsymbol {\theta}})$ mean.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X)$ is a vector of estimators and $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol{\psi}}({\boldsymbol {\theta}})$ is its expectation. That is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X)\right] = \displaystyle {\boldsymbol{\psi}}({\boldsymbol {\theta}}).
$$

As an example, consider a random sample from a univariate Normal distribution. Then ${\boldsymbol {\theta}} = (\mu, \sigma^2)^T$, $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X) = \left(\sum_i X_i , \sum_i X_i^2\right)^T$ and $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol{\psi}}({\boldsymbol {\theta}}) = (n\mu, n\sigma^2 + n\mu^2)^T$.

Comment: This may sound silly and I am sorry for that. I am interested in deciding a confidence interval for two parameters, then how do I get $\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {T}}(X)$ and $ {\boldsymbol{\psi}}({\boldsymbol {\theta}})$

Comment: yes I understand that, CRLB provides me a confidence interval. My problem: I have optimized a loss function with respect to two parameters and I am interested in obtaining a confidence band for them. I am available with Hessian matrix.

Comment: @pkj oh my fault, yeah if you're using maximum likelihood, you can get the "observed information" by looking at the negative Hessian. Then to get the covariance matrix you take the inverse of that; that's the CRLB.

Comment: on the last page of this document http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old03/5102/notes/fish.pdf , you have $\mathbf{t}$ and I do not know what is that

Comment: @pkj that's a different "t". That one is a vector of weights. If you want to only have a CI for the first parameter, $\mathbf{t} = (1,0,0,\ldots)$. If you want an interval for the difference of the first two parameters, then $\mathbf{t} = (1,-1,0,\ldots)$. If you have separate questions, those should go in a different thread. Regarding what to do with your Hessian, that depends if you're minimizing the negative log likelihood or maximizing the log-likelihood. It will also depend on whether or not you scaled it.

Comment: Thank you @Taylor, you have been generous enough and spared time to answer my doubts. I thought the $t$s are same. I will give it another try, if I could not succeed, I will draft an another question. Thank you again.